# Lazy Loading search HomeComponent who is not used in the module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem with Lazy Loading in Angular.
I have module `ShopCartModule` who I have to implement Lazy Loading.

I have `AppModule` and `CoreModule`.

This is my `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CoreModule,
    ShopCartModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    AboutModule,
    ContactModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    NgbActiveModal
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

And this is my CoreModule :

```
@NgModule({


    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        CarouselModule.forRoot(),
        SharedModule,
        SlickCarouselModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule
    ],
    exports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        HeaderComponent,
        FooterComponent

    ],
    declarations: [
        HeaderComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        LogoutComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        DataStorageService,
        ProductsService,
        ShopCartService,
        AdminSerivice,
        MessageService,
        CategoryService,
        ProductService,
        EmailService,
        AuthenticationService,
        BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService,
        ProductModelOrder,
        {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService, multi: true}
    ]
})
export class CoreModule {
}
```

I have the `app-routing.module` the main router module:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'o-nama', component: AboutComponent},
  { path: 'kontakt', component: ContactComponent},
  { path: 'shopCart', loadChildren:'./shop-cart/shop-cart.module#ShopCartModule' },
  { path: 'administration', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule', canActivate: [AuthGaurdService] },
  { path: 'productsList', loadChildren: './products/products.module#ProductsModule' },
  { path: 'not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And this is my router module for shop-cart:

```
const shopCartRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: ShopCartComponent
    },

]
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(shopCartRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class ShopCartRoutingModule{}
```

I have error like this:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
```

But I do not use my HomeComponent in the module, I do not understand what is problem. Everting work well when I do not implement lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe issue is with loading order of file, can you give it a try using below code -

```
....
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,    // Interchanged the order here in order to make HomeComponent available before routing file.
    AppRoutingModule,
    ShopCartModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    AboutModule,
    ContactModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
.....
```

Update -

```
imports: [
  ....
  // Specify your library as an import
  SlickCarouselModule   // You need to add SlickCarousel Module here before use
  ....
]
```

Comment: @SInsansun IMO you should add `HomeComponent` into the `AppModule` itself, as it is always recommended to add entery level component in `AppModule`

Comment: A trued this and I have this error:
`Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "slick-carousel" ("
        </div>
    </div>
    <ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" [ERROR ->]#slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
        <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of "): ng:///AppModule/HomeComponent.html@65:41
Can't bind to 'config' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-slick-carousel'.`

Comment: Yes this problem is something different, you can ask new question for the same. If problem solved for this question/query mart it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `HomeComponent` into exports if you want to use it anywhere outside of `CoreModule`

Comment: I added the `HomeComponent` to the export and I still have this error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first error that I see is the order of the imports in the modules. the Angular modules should be first (CommonModule, BrowserModule, FormsModule). Then if you have the "moduleA" that uses the "moduleB", so the order should be imported: [moduleB, moduleA].

Second, you are importing the AppRouting Module more than once, it should be imported only once (Do it in the AppModule or in the CoreModule).

Third, you have to import the HttpClientModule only once (Do it in the AppModule or in the CoreModule). If you imported more than once you will reinitialize the interceptors.

```
**AppModule**

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,
    ShopCartModule,
    AboutModule,
    ContactModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    NgbActiveModal
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

**CoreModule :**

@NgModule({

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    CarouselModule.forRoot(),
    SharedModule,
    SlickCarouselModule
],
exports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent

],
declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LogoutComponent
],
providers: [
    DataStorageService,
    ProductsService,
    ShopCartService,
    AdminSerivice,
    MessageService,
    CategoryService,
    ProductService,
    EmailService,
    AuthenticationService,
    BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService,
    ProductModelOrder,
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService, multi: true}
]
})
export class CoreModule {
}
```

Try it now.